# Not able to append the div using click event of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys I want to dynamically append the div to the div that i click. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
 <script src="query.js">
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
    }); 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hello1">Hello guys</div>
<div class="hello2">Hiiiiiiii</div>
<div class="hello3">Awesome</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me whats the issue with my code

Comment: You have no element with the `.hello` class, try either `class="hello someotherclass"` in your _hello_ divs or `$('.hello1', '.hello2', ...)` in your JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrap your jquery code in `document.ready` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // this will execute when DOM is ready
  //your code 
  $('.hello1').click(function(){ //updated class name
    $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
  });
})
```

> As i can see you are using `hello` class to bind click event your it
>   doesn't present in your HTML. So if you want to attach event to all
>   class start with `hello` use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[class^="hello"]').click(function(){
        $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
    }); 
});
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/z23L1rzb/)

Instead of this

```
<script src="query.js"> //don't use src here
```

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: It will work. Best answer because i do not need to change the class name, it works for any class which begins with the "hello" name.

Comment: Ya this is because of jqeury selector `^`. Enjoy scripting.

Comment: Hey Manwal can i make this dynamically created div to toggle??

Comment: Yes sure try this `$('body').find('#divID').toggle()`.

Comment: Hey First I want to dynamically create the div on first click ,in next click div should go away. This process should repeat.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 problems in your code

1. You can't have src and contents for an script tag
2. Since your script is placed before the elements are loaded, you need to put your script in a dom ready handler
3. There is no class called hello in your html

so

```
<div class="hello">Hello guys</div>
<div class="hello">Hiiiiiiii</div>
<div class="hello">Awesome</div>

<script src="query.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.hello').click(function () {
            $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You don't have div with `class="hello"` but class which starts with `hello` viz `hello1`, `hello2`, `hello3`. Hence use start with selector as shown below. Also put your code inside `$(document).ready(function...` or `$(function(){...` so that it will ensure DOM is ready and will attach click event handler.

You must include jquery library first and then put jquery script in another script tag.

```
<script src="query.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('div[class^="hello"]').click(function(){
            $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to include jQuery before and for using it. Use

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. You cannot load script and define script inside it. So, following is not valid

   ```
   <script src="query.js">$('.hello')...</script>
   ```
3. Use `ready()` or `DOMContentLoaded` event or move the script to the bottom of `<body>`
4. There is no element with `hello` class in the markup, but you're binding the event on it.

Code:

```
<script src="query.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hello').click(function() {
        $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hello').click(function() {
    $(this).append('<div>I am the new one</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello">Hello guys</div>
<div class="hello">Hiiiiiiii</div>
<div class="hello">Awesome</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.hello` class in your code, you use `hello1`, `hello2` and `hello3` as classnames, they should all just be `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to use $() selectors you need to include a proper version of jquery. Then, you need to select an element: you have any element with hello class, instead, you have hello1, hello2, and hello3. You could remove the numbers, so all of them will have a hello class. And finally, because these elements doesn't exist when the js code is executed, you need to wrap your code within a document ready event, or move it to the end of your html body tag. Good luck!